# xgboost with H2o on Windows

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o, xgboost

According to the docs, `xgboost` is not supported on `h2o windows OS`. Is it still the case? Is there a workaround?

Really want to use on windows machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this post, H2O-3 does not yet have native support of xgboost on Windows.

Your best bet in the short term is to try WSL, docker, or a virtual machine like VMware workstation or Virtualbox.

Of those options, at the moment, I would favor WSL.